# Use of Undeclared type 'NSEvent'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a mouse down event, but keep getting the error "Use of undeclared type 'NSEvent'" on the "override func mouseDown( theEvent: NSEvent!) { " line. After researching and trying different things, I still got nothing. Anyone had this problem before?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


let BallCategoryName = "ball"
let MainBallCategoryName = "mainBall"

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)

        // 1. Create a physics body that borders the screen
        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        // 2. Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
        borderBody.friction = 0
        // 3. Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
        self.physicsBody = borderBody

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

        let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode
        var mainBall = childNodeWithName(MainBallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode

    ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

    ball.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody!.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0

}

override func mouseDown( theEvent: NSEvent!) {
    let action = SKAction.moveTo(
        CGPoint(x:theEvent.locationInWindow.x,y:theEvent.locationInWindow.y),
        duration:2
    );
    MainBallCategoryName.runAction(action)

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices don't have mice, and iOS doesn't have an `NSEvent` class. It has a `UIEvent` class, but there's nothing special about a function named `mouseDown` on iOS.  iOS events report touches, not mouse buttons.

If you copied this code from a tutorial, the tutorial was for OS X, not iOS. You should find an iOS tutorial instead.

Answer (score 1):

In an OS X app you should not:

```
import UIKit
```

but instead use

```
import AppKit
```

Comment: I add import AppKit, and get "no such module 'AppKit'"

Comment: Check your app's deployment/build target - it is set to OS X, right? Because considering that you had no problems importing UIKit I bet the target is set to compile for iOS rather than OS X.
Also try `import Cocoa` not sure if Swift prefers that.